# I have an exception like invalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Here is the exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [java.lang.String (n/a)]; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [java.lang.String (n/a)]
```

Here is my Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface FirmRepository extends JpaRepository<Firm, Integer> {
    Page<Firm> findAll(Pageable page);

    List<Firm> findByParentFirm(Firm firm);

    @Query(value = "FROM Firm WHERE name = :name")
    Firm findByName(@Param("name") final String[] name);
}
```

Here is my Service:

```
   /**
     * Gets the Application type by name
     */
    public Firm getFirmByName(final String[] name) throws ResourceNotFoundException, ForbiddenOperationException {
        //LOGGER.debug("Getting the firm  with name=[{}]", strings);
        return firmRepository.findByName(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to look if the values contained in this array exist in my database
String[] tabFirmName = line[0].split(",");

Comment: what shoul i do then?

Comment: I dont know about JPA, but the query itself doesn't look like it would work. You should be using `name IN ()`  As mentioned in the comment before, try to pluralize the names and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work

```
@Query( "FROM Firm WHERE name in :names" )
List<Firm> findByName(@Param("names") List<String> firmNames);
```

You can convert the array to list as `List<String> firmNames = Arrays.asList(names);`